# Unable to run PHPUnit test in PHPStorm

Tags: php, unit-testing, header, phpunit, phpstorm

I have a test suite running on PHPUnit using the PHPStorm IDE. But, one of the tests used to fail due to the following issue, 
`PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...`

I managed fixed that by adding the `@runInSeparateProcess` annotation.

I was able to run all the tests successfully in the terminal. But when I try to run the tests using the PHPStorm IDE, I end up getting the following error message -

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception : PHPUnit 4.2.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Usage: phpunit [options] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]
       phpunit [options] <directory>
Code Coverage Options:

--coverage-clover <file>  Generate code coverage report in Clover XML format.

...(basically prints out the output of phpunit --help)
```

This is seen only while running the same test that failed earlier with the header error message.

Please assist me to fix this issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you run your tests? Simply the right click > run?

Comment: Yes. I right-click the phpunit.xml file and run it.

Comment: Such case is not supported: you have to point to test file (or whole folder) but not `.xml` file.

Comment: @LazyOne, Really? Did you even try that before making a statement? Your name says otherwise…

Comment: The whole folder is pointed in the .xml file. The IDE basically runs the following command `phpunit --stderr --configuration (path-to-xml-file)/phpunit.xml`.

Comment: @Josh did you try deleting all (relevant) run configurations in run > edit configurations?

Comment: Yep! No difference. I get the same error message.

Comment: Did you manage to run the tests before in PhpStorm at all? Are you trying to configure it to work with the existing suite / config? Or did it get broken?

Comment: Nope. I was never able to get the tests running in the IDE. I usually use the terminal to run them. This is the first time I tried to run the tests in PHPStorm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61442/discussion-between-ian-bytchek-and-josh).

Comment: @IanBytchek Of course I did. You appears to be fast on judging people by their names/nicknames. Good

Comment: @LazyOne I was not the one who "appears to be fast on judging people by their names/nicknames". Please read the comments properly.

Comment: @Josh ... oh -- sorry -- my mistake

Comment: @LazyOne, that was supposed to be a fun comment. The point is that it works fine for me, though I never supposed that it can work this way.

Comment: @IanBytchek *Possibly* it worked in previous versions (be it PhpStorm or PHPUnit) ... but it does not in current v8.0 and 4.2.x. testing individual class/whole folder works great though. What command PhpStorm uses when executing this way in your case?

Comment: @LazyOne, 8 came out two days ago, I'm still on EAP which must be 99.9999999999% identical. http://cl.ly/image/1B3h3g0D2j2o

Comment: @IanBytchek 1) Your screencast tells me that you have already setup proper run config for that. In other words -- it's not created on the fly but uses existing one. If you would be creating it on the fly it should have "Run" and other options in submenus; 2) It may also depend on what's in `phpunit.xml`

Comment: @LazyOne, we slowly moved from how this case is not supported to a different discussion. Join the chat, perhaps you can help. I don't really know what else to suggest there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally managed to fix it! I removed the `@runInSeparateProcess` annotation for the test that was failing and also the `--stderr` option in the run configurations. Instead, I added `stderr="true"` option in the **phpunit** tag present in the **phpunit.xml** and it worked. Strange.

Thank you [Ian Bytchek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458356/ian-bytchek) for your time and effort. :)