# Headers already sent running unit tests in PHPStorm

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

I'm trying to use the integrated method of running phpunit tests within PHPStorm and having some issues getting it to work.

PHP: 5.6.10
PHPUnit: 4.5.1
PHPStorm: 8.0.3

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/30345501/1636594 I learned that I had to downgrade my phpunit version to < 4.6.

Finding https://stackoverflow.com/a/25903332/1636594 I tried both @runInSeparateProcess notation and strerr="false|true" in my configuration. With process isolation, I saw the same issue as this user (basically phpunit --help instead of each test in isolation). With stderr="false|true" I get the same either way (Cannot modify header information... blah blah).

The tests run fine without process isolation or stderr set to either one of true or false, both give successful passing tests.
[image: Screenshot of tests passing in terminal, failing in integrated runner]

For now I'm obviously just running my tests in the terminal, but I would really like to be able to use the coverage feature but its basically useless for any line of code after a header call.

Comment: I may only suggest trying [`-d output_buffering=On`](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-8994#comment=27-346846) under "Interpreter Option"

Comment: Thanks LazyOne, I have just tried this but it did not work. :(

Answer (score 18):

I had same problem. When I try to run any of the codeception tests (specifically for Yii2) with the built-in PHPStorm tools, I get the message:

`session_set_cookie_params(): Cannot change session cookie parameters when headers already sent`

I didn’t reach a long time, but yesterday after midnight dances with universal tambourines I found out literally the following:

PHPStorm (jetBrains for Google) uses the Codeception Framework plugin to place the file:

`C:/Users/dev/AppData/Local/Temp/ide-codeception_before_24.php:405`

from which, using the `printEvent` method, logs to the console via `Printer::write()`:

`vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php:99`

how to fix it nicely, I did not find, so "here is our answer to Chamberlain!": we write `ob_start()` in `tests/_bootstrap.php`:

```php
<?php
require_once __DIR__. '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
require_once __DIR__. '/ .. / vendor / autoload.php';

ob_start();
```

the buffer is flushed to the console automatically at the end of the tests. We get the following:

[image: Example of running codeception run tests functional]

Comment: It works, but ofcourse with output buffering on we don't get any feedback while the tests are running.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the ApiTester was getting an error when trying to set Headers for the request because content had already been sent.

I solved it by creating an extension to capture output then flush the buffer between tests and at the end so error output is not lost.

**tests/extensions/ApiOutputBuffer.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\tests\extensions;

use Codeception\Extension;
use Codeception\Events;
use Codeception\Event\SuiteEvent;
use Codeception\Event\TestEvent;

class ApiOutputBuffer extends Extension {
    public static $events = [
        Events::SUITE_BEFORE => 'startOutputBuffer',
        Events::TEST_END => 'flushBuffer',
        Events::SUITE_AFTER => 'endOutputBuffer',
    ];

    public function startOutputBuffer( SuiteEvent $e ) {
        ob_start();
    }

    public function flushBuffer( TestEvent $e ) {
        ob_flush();
    }

    public function endOutputBuffer( SuiteEvent $e ) {
         ob_end_flush();
    }
}
```

**tests/api.suite.yml** (your's may differ, the `extensions` is what matters)

```
actor: ApiTester
bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Api
        - REST:
                url: /
                depends: Yii2
extensions:
    enabled:
        - app\tests\extensions\ApiOutputBuffer
```

**tests/_bootstrap.php** (your's may differ, requiring ApiOutputBuffer is what matters)

```
<?php
define('YII_ENV', 'test');
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/extensions/ApiOutputBuffer.php';
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be fixed by setting the PHP error reporting level to `E_ERROR` before the the call to the code that eventually results in the error:

```
...
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
expect_not($this->model->login());
...
```

For a unit test, this can be achieved for all test functions by calling  `error_reporting()` inside `_before()`:

```
protected function _before()
{
    parent::_before();
    error_reporting(E_ERROR);
}
```

At a higher level, we can replace the default codeception error reporting level of unit tests by setting `error_level` in `unit.suite.yml`:

```
class_name: UnitTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - Asserts
    - Yii2:
        part: [orm, email, fixtures]
error_level: "E_ERROR"
```